# Update ListView after deleting from database android

Tags: android, listview

After deleting from database my ListView does not update , I found a method on stackoverflow by it does not work, here is how I populate my list:

```
...
private ListView list;
ListAdapter adapter; (ListAdapter is a class from here i set the layout of a row)
...
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     ...
      database info = new database(this);
  info.open();
  data = info.getData2();
  data2 = info.getData3();
  info.close();   
  list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);   
  adapter=new ListAdapter(this, data , data2);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
      registerForContextMenu(list);
      ...
      ...
 }

 ...
 ...
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =(AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        ...
        ...
        if(menuItemName.equals("Delete")){
        menuItemName = "2";
        Log.i(TAG,"Primul "+listItemName + " " + " al doilea " + listItemName2);
        database delete = new database(this);
        delete.open();          
    delete.deleteEntryFromList(listItemName,listItemName2);
    delete.close();
        //here i am suposed to do
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //but it does not work
        }
 }
```

Can somebody help me here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always have problems with the notify methods. Easiest solution: Create a method that is called updateAdapter(), replace the notify call with that and put this in it:

```
  private void updateAdapter(){
  database info = new database(this);
  info.open();
  data = info.getData2();
  data2 = info.getData3();
  info.close();   
  list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);   
  adapter=new ListAdapter(this, data , data2);
  list.setAdapter(adapter);
      registerForContextMenu(list);
}
```

Call that instead of the notify* method.

Comment: no , still does not work; it does not remove the item from list after deleting it from database

Comment: Please post this code: delete.deleteEntryFromList(listItemName,listItemName2); Maybe you are not actually deleting the item

Comment: i`m deleting it from database , i`m very sure. If i delete it , leave the activity and come back it is not there , i even checked it from adb

Comment: I believe you are keeping a reference to data and data2. See my edited answer. I still think a different updateAdapter method should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the data youre having in the varibals data = info.getData2(); and
  data2 = info.getData3(); then you say adapter.notifiDataSetChanged and it will update youre listview

EDIT
bettter answere

```
database delete = new database(this);
    delete.open();          
delete.deleteEntryFromList(listItemName,listItemName2);
delete.close();
     database info = new database(this);
info.open();
 data = info.getData2();
data2 = info.getData3();
info.close();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: how to do that ? i called again the database filled in the data and data2 and say adapter.notifiDataSetChanged

Comment: i just checked it.sorry if it is a dumb question but i tried like almost everything